# No obj-c interfaces generated for swift classes in mixed Swift Obj-C framework unit tests target

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, frameworks, module-map

I have a mixed Swift Obj-C framework. Inside framework target there is a modulemap file with next contents:

```
framework module ObjCSwiftMix {
    umbrella "."

    export *
}
```

I also have couple of files:

- A) Obj-C protocol
- B) Obj-C class
- C) Swift class, that uses Obj-C protocol
- D) Swift class, that uses Obj-C class
- E) Swift class

In framework target settings:
`MODULEMAP_FILE` is set to point to that file, `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = YES`, `DEFINES_MODULE = YES`.

Inside Unit Tests Target - mocks of swift classes, all Obj-C compatible.
So the problem is, that the only interface in Generated Header file (`*Tests-Swift.h` file) is swift class, that uses Obj-C protocol (**C** in list). Interface for **D** and **E** is not generated.

Code of mocks:

```swift
import Foundation
@testable import ObjCSwiftMix

// No Obj-C Interface in ObjCSwiftMixTests-Swift.h
@objcMembers
@objc
public final class VersionProviderSpy: VersionProvider {
    public var returnedVersion: Double! = 42
    public var valudue: Any!

    public override func version() -> Double {
        returnedVersion
    }
}
```

```swift
@testable import ObjCSwiftMix

// No Obj-C Interface in ObjCSwiftMixTests-Swift.h
@objc(OSMAssetsReportParametersProviderSpy)
@objcMembers
public class AssetsReportParametersProviderSpy: AssetsReportParametersProvider {

    public var passedAssetAdapters: [String: OSMNativeAssetBindingAdapter] = [:]
    public var returnedAssetsReportParameters: [String: [String: Any]] = [:]
    public var assetsReportParametersCalled = false

    public init() {
        super.init(assetViews: [:], providedAssets: [])
    }

    public override func assetsReportParameters(
        assetAdapters: [String: OSMNativeAssetBindingAdapter]
    ) -> [String: [String: Any]] {
        passedAssetAdapters = assetAdapters
        assetsReportParametersCalled = true
        return returnedAssetsReportParameters
    }
}
```

But for that one interface is generated:

```swift
import UIKit
@testable import ObjCSwiftMix

// Ok Obj-C interface is generated
@objcMembers
final class VideoViewProviderSpy: NSObject, OSMAVideoViewProvider {

    var invokedGetView = false
    var invokedGetViewCount = 0
    var stubbedGetViewResult: UIView?

    func getView() -> UIView? {
        invokedGetView = true
        invokedGetViewCount += 1
        return stubbedGetViewResult
    }
}
```

For better understanding, a have made a [sample project `ObjCSwiftMix`](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/xLJQSf_La8W-6A). To reproduce the error build `ObjCSwiftMixTest` scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved with setting `IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=13.0` for test target.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).